# Once more about removing duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, duplicates, on-duplicate-key, arrays

After an exhausting search I found some similar problems like the one I would like to solve, but I could not use their answers.

Hier are some very good examples:

[How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

[How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

[How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP revisited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139377/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php-revisited)

This one is the most similar, but the answer somehow doesn't work to me.

[php filter array values and remove duplicates from multi dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001121/php-filter-array-values-and-remove-duplicates-from-multi-dimensional-array)

The main difference to my issue is that while people are looking for a solution to delete an entire duplicated subarray from the array, I'm trying to delete the subarray when only one $key => $value pair of the subarray is similar to the correspondent pair of another subarray. The other pairs could have different values or even the same.

Here my array:

```
Array(

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => AAA
        [1] => 500
    )

[1] => Array //Won't be delete 'cause [0] is different, although [1] is the same.
    (
        [0] => BBB
        [1] => 500
    )

[2] => Array //Will be delete 'cause [0] is the same.
    (
        [0] => AAA
        [1] => 500
    )

[3] => Array //Won't be delete 'cause [0] is different.
    (
        [0] => CCC
        [1] => 820
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => AAA //Will be delete 'cause [0] is the same. [1] is also different.
        [1] => 774
    )
```

How could I manage to delete these subarrays so I have following result:

```
Array(

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => AAA
        [1] => 500
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => BBB
        [1] => 500
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => CCC
        [1] => 820
    )
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution (in my opinion), instead of using magical `array_filter` and `array_map` handicraft which is difficult to maintain, is to write a specialized function yourself:

```
$out = [];
$usedKeys = [];
foreach ($in as $element)
{
    list ($a, $b) = $element;
    if (!isset($usedKeys[$a]))
    {
        $usedKeys[$a] = true;
        $out[]= $element;
    }
}
var_dump($out);
```

This will return only elements whose first pair element is unique (taking first one, if multiple entries are available).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (based on the link provided):

```
<?php

$items = array(
    array(
        0 => 'AAA',
        1 => 500,
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'BBB',
        1 => 500,
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'AAA',
        1 => 500,
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'CCC',
        1 => 820,
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'AAA',
        1 => 774,
    ),
);




$taken = array();

foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    if(!in_array($item[0], $taken)) {
        $taken[] = $item[0];
    } else {
        unset($items[$key]);
    }
}


echo '<pre>'.print_r($items,true).'</pre>';
```

[fiddle link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cYddVg)